Unable to create a vectorstore retriever using Chroma
I am trying to implement RAG with the GPT-3.5 api. However, my code execution gets stuck while trying to create the retriever. I didn't get this issue on Google Colab but I started getting this issue once I shifted my codebase to my local environment.
Here is the function:
    def create_retriever(docs_list,embeddings_model):

        try:
            text_splitter = TextSplitter((200,1000))
            texts = [doc.page_content for doc in docs_list]
            metadata_list = [doc.metadata for doc in docs_list]
            print("INIT done!")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in split init: ",e)
        try:
            # Split the text and convert to Document objects
            doc_splits = []
            for i in range(len(texts)):
                text = texts[i]
                metadata = metadata_list[i]
                chunks = text_splitter.chunks(text)
                for chunk in chunks:
                    doc_splits.append(Document(page_content=chunk, metadata = metadata))  # can add the kind of code in metadata
            print("SPLITTING done!")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in splitting: ",e)

        try:
                
            # Add to vectorDB
            vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
                documents=doc_splits,
                collection_name="rag-chroma",
                embedding=embeddings_model,
            )
            retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()
            print("Retriever created: ", retriever)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in creating the retriever object: ",e)
        return retriever

The output that I get is as follows:
.
.
.
INIT done!
SPLITTING done!
INFO:backoff:Backing off send_request(...) for 0.5s (requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='us-api.i.posthog.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /batch/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)'))))
I have tried to re-install/upgrade my dependencies to their latest versions but to no avail. Should I switch to other vectorstores like FAISS?
